# I've set my Python multi-threaded logging handlers to different levels, but why do they still handle all level of messages?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, logging, thread-safety

I wanted to have a logger that could log messages at different levels without blocking, so I wrote the following code based on the example provided in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#dealing-with-handlers-that-block). According to the documentation, the `logging` module is thread-safe and the `INFO` level is higher than the `DEBUG` level.

I wanted to have 2 types of handlers. One of them prints every message to `sys.stdout`, so I set the logging level of that handler to `DEBUG`. The other handler only writes messages to a file with levels above `INFO`, so I set the logging level of that handler to `INFO`. In order for the logger to log every message, I set the logging level of the logger to `INFO`.

However, when I log a message with `DEBUG` level, the message is also written to the file, which is not expected. Why does this happen? How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

```py
import logging
from logging.handlers import QueueHandler, QueueListener
from queue import Queue
import sys

debug_queue = Queue(-1)  # no limit on size
debug_queue_handler = QueueHandler(debug_queue)
debug_handler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
debug_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
debug_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s:\t%(message)s'))
debug_listener = QueueListener(debug_queue, debug_handler)

info_queue = Queue(-1)  # no limit on size
info_queue_handler = QueueHandler(info_queue)
info_handler = logging.FileHandler("results.csv", "w")
info_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
info_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(message)s'))
info_listener = QueueListener(info_queue, info_handler)

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(debug_queue_handler)
logger.addHandler(info_queue_handler)

debug_listener.start()
info_listener.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

> Changed in version 3.5: Prior to Python 3.5, the `QueueListener` always passed every message received from the queue to every handler it was initialized with. (This was because it was assumed that level filtering was all done on the other side, where the queue is filled.) From 3.5 onwards, this behaviour can be changed by passing a keyword argument `respect_handler_level=True` to the listener’s constructor. When this is done, the listener compares the level of each message with the handler’s level, and only passes a message to a handler if it’s appropriate to do so.

So I passed a keyword argument `respect_handler_level=True` to the listener's constructor and that solved it. Sorry for not reading the documentation carefully.

Comment: NIcely done. That just saved me too!